Search for documents about the function $ x \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos{(2^n x)}}{n!} $
While consulting a Wikipedia page (in French) devoted to Taylor power series (here), I came across the example below of a real function due to the Czech mathematician Matyáš Lerch:
$$ x \mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos{(2^n x)}}{n!} $$
And it is indicated that this function has the particularity of having a "convergence radius" equal to $0$ at all points (if I understand correctly what is said).
As I do not see at all what this means (since this function does not appear in the form of a usual power series...), my question is simply: does this function tell you anything in particular? Do you have any references to documents that talk about it?
Thanks for any guidance.

Not a function I've seen before. The series does converge for all $x$. I think you can prove that you can  differentiate the series term by term. That might be interesting.

The claim is not that the series does not converge (it does converge, for all $x$) but seems to be that the Taylor series around any $x$ does not have a positive radius of convergence.

For real $x$, this is a uniformly convergent series of smooth functions, and the series of $k$'th derivatives is uniformly convergent for all $k$: note that
$$ \left|\dfrac{d^k}{dx^k} \frac{\cos(2^n x)}{n!}\right| = \left|\pm \frac{2^{nk} \cos(2^n x)}{n!} \ \text{or} \pm\frac{2^{nk} \sin(2^n x)}{n!}\right| \le \frac{2^{nk}}{n!}$$
(with $+ \cos$, $-\sin$, $-\cos$ and $+\sin$ for $k \equiv 0,1, 2, 3 \pmod 4$ respectively).
Thus the sum of the series is a smooth function: call it $f(x)$.
However, the Taylor series of this function does not converge.
For example, taking $x = 0$,
$$    f^{(k)}(0) = \cases{\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{2^{nk}}{n!} = \exp(2^k) & if $k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$\cr
\sum_{n=0}^\infty  -\frac{2^{nk}}{n!} = -\exp(2^k) & if $k \equiv 2 \pmod 4$\cr
0 & otherwise }$$
and the Taylor series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} z^k$ has radius of convergence $0$.

Hi, I appreciate your answer which opens up perspectives for studying this function. If I continue your argument, we should have $ |f^{(k)} (x)| \leq \exp^{(2^k)} $, right?
On the other hand, concerning your last assertion, how do you manage to deduce that the radius of convergence is $0$, from the sole expression of $ f^{(k)} (0) $. What step of reasoning am I missing to conclude?

If $b(k) = \exp(2^k)/k!$, then $b(k)/b(k-1) = \exp(2^{k-1})/k \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$.

Of course! Thank you for this feedback.
By the way, in case you or some others feel interested in this function, I finally found an article that discusses it:
“A $C^{\infty}$ nowhere analytic function. A forgotten example from 1888”
https://dml.cz/handle/10338.dmlcz/501870
